# Replace negative values with previous row / 2

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to adjust val column so that there will not be any negative values.

Ajusting rule is,

- replace negative value with half of previous row
- do this for each hier ( group_by(hier) )
- if more than one negative values consecutive, divide previous adjusted value to 2

  ```
  xdat <- data.frame( 
    hier = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5) )
    , val = c(4, 7, -3, 10, 5, 1, -7, -4, 5, 7)
             )

  hier |  val | val_adjust
  A    |  4   |    4
  A    |  7   |    7
  A    |  -3  |    3.5
  A    |  10  |    10
  A    |  5   |    5
  B    |  1   |    1
  B    |  -7  |    0.5
  B    |  -4  |    0.25
  B    |  5   |    5
  B    |  7   |    7
  ```

Comment: What if the first value in a hier is negative?

Comment: In my case it won't, but my suggestion is to write half of the lowest value

Comment: `xdat$val2 <- ave(xdat$val, xdat$hier, FUN = function(x) {while (any(x < 0)) x[x < 0] <- c(0, head(x, -1) / 2)[x < 0]; x})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
 xdat%>%group_by(hier)%>%mutate(adj_val=accumulate(val,~ifelse(.y<0,.x/2,.y)))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   hier [2]
     hier   val adj_val
   <fctr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1      A     4    4.00
 2      A     7    7.00
 3      A    -3    3.50
 4      A    10   10.00
 5      A     5    5.00
 6      B     1    1.00
 7      B    -7    0.50
 8      B    -4    0.25
 9      B     5    5.00
10      B     7    7.00
```

In base R you can do something like:

```
transform(xdat,y=unlist(tapply(val,hier,FUN=Reduce,f=function(x,y)ifelse(y<0,x/2,y),accumulate=T)))
   hier val     y
A1    A   4  4.00
A2    A   7  7.00
A3    A  -3  3.50
A4    A  10 10.00
A5    A   5  5.00
B1    B   1  1.00
B2    B  -7  0.50
B3    B  -4  0.25
B4    B   5  5.00
B5    B   7  7.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer while generating reproducible question

```
xdat %>% 
  rowid_to_column("rowid") %>% 
  group_by(hier) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = rank(rowid)) %>% 
  mutate(val_adj1 = lag(val)) %>% 
  mutate(val_adj1 = case_when(val < 0~val_adj1/2, TRUE~val)) %>% 
  mutate(val_adj2 = lag(val_adj1)) %>% 
  mutate(val_adj2 = case_when(val_adj1 < 0~val_adj2/2, TRUE~val_adj1))
```

generates

```
   rowid   hier   val val_adj1 val_adj2
   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1      A     4      4.0     4.00
 2     2      A     7      7.0     7.00
 3     3      A    -3      3.5     3.50
 4     4      A    10     10.0    10.00
 5     5      A     5      5.0     5.00
 6     1      B     1      1.0     1.00
 7     2      B    -7      0.5     0.50
 8     3      B    -4     -3.5     0.25
 9     4      B     5      5.0     5.00
10     5      B     7      7.0     7.00
```